# Classify across ten methods

Tags: programming, machine-learning

Mathematica supports ten different methods for [*Classify*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html).

The ten methods are:    "ClassDistributions", "DecisionTree", "GradientBoostedTrees", "LogisticRegression", "Markov", "NaiveBayes", "NearestNeighbors", "NeuralNetwork", "RandomForest", "SupportVectorMachine".

Here is an example using the first method.

```
  resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
  trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
  testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];

  trainingData // Length

  c1 = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "ClassDistributions"]

  cm1 = ClassifierMeasurements[c1, testData]

  cm1["AccuracyRejectionPlot"]
```

My question

What is the best approach to repeat this for each of the ten methods and take the classifier results and accuracy rejection plots and put them in a grid for each method?

I was doing the same three steps method by method, but that seems clunky.

Next steps are to play around with various other approaches  like [*convolutional neural networks*](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/measure-classification-performance.html?product=language) and [*LeNet*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksIntroduction.html) variants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** Add example of other `ClassifierMeasurementsObject` properties.

The code will work for any property that is a `Graphics` e.g. for `"ConfusionMatrixPlot"`

```
confusionMatrixPlots = #["ConfusionMatrixPlot"] & /@ classifierMeasurements;

KeyValueMap[Show[#2, PlotLabel -> #1, ImageSize -> 300] &, confusionMatrixPlots] // 
Partition[#, UpTo@3] & // 
Grid[#, Alignment -> Bottom, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

---

Map over the available methods

```
methods = {"ClassDistributions", "DecisionTree", "GradientBoostedTrees",
           "LogisticRegression", "Markov", "NaiveBayes", "NearestNeighbors",
           "NeuralNetwork", "RandomForest", "SupportVectorMachine"};

(* Only 100 examples and TimeGoal = 5s for testing *)
classifiers = 
  AssociationMap[
   Classify[RandomSample[trainingData, 100], TimeGoal -> 5, Method -> #] &, methods];

classifierMeasurements = 
 ClassifierMeasurements[#, RandomSample[testData, 100]] & /@ classifiers;

accuracyRejectionPlots = #["AccuracyRejectionPlot"] & /@ classifierMeasurements;

KeyValueMap[Show[#2, PlotLabel -> #1, ImageSize -> 300] &, accuracyRejectionPlots] // 
Partition[#, UpTo@3] & // 
Grid[#, Alignment -> Bottom, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the second variant that uses the entire datasets as a second variant, or better yet, let the user choose based on some flag?

Comment: I don't have a GPU so training on 60000 images would take a long time for each method so I chose 100. To use a different number change `RandomSample[trainingData, 100]` to `RandomSample[trainingData, n]` where `n <= Length@trainingData` and `RandomSample[testData, 100]]` to `RandomSample[testData, m]]` where `m <= Length@testData`. Also remove `TimeGoal -> 5`.

Comment: `n / m` should be `~ 6` (ratio between training and testing sample lengths)